# Removing element after sliding up animation and contrary, mounting the element before sliding down in Vue 3.X

Tags: vue.js, animation, vuejs3, slidetoggle

The [vue-slide-up-down](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-slide-up-down) library working with pre-mounted elements only.

- **Sliding down case:** It will not mount the element before animation starts
- **Sliding up case:** It will not unmount the element after animation ends

It just manipulating with the element's height and `hidden` attribute.

Now what if I don't what the target element be mounted when it does not displaying?

- **Sliding down case:** Before animation starts, I want the element be mounted
- **Sliding up case:** Once animation complete, I want the element be unmounted, not just hidden

If we try

```
<slide-up-down 
  v-if="active"
  :active="active" 
>
  Only show this if "active” is true
</slide-up-down>
```

it will not be the animation because:

- **Sliding down case:** animation starts before element mounted
- **Sliding up case:** the element will be unmounted before animation starts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a separate variable controlling whether the component is rendered (I named it `isRendered` below).
And a setter + getter computed (named `rendered` below) which sets both `active` and `isRendered` to current value, but in different order:

- when setting to `true`: turn `isRendered` on first, then set `active` to `true` in `$nextTick`, so the animation is played
- when setting to `false`: turn `active` to `false` first, wait for animation to finish and then set `isRendered` to `false`.

---

**Vue2 demo**:

```js
Vue.component("slide-up-down", VueSlideUpDown)
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    isRendered: false,
    active: false,
    duration: 500
  }),
  computed: {
    rendered: {
      get() {
        return this.isRendered
      },
      set(val) {
        if (val) {
          this.isRendered = val
          this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.active = val
          })
        } else {
          this.active = val
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.isRendered = val
          }, this.duration)
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.wrap {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

button {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.7.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-slide-up-down@2.0.0/dist/vue-slide-up-down.umd.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="rendered = !rendered">Toggle</button>
  <slide-up-down v-if="isRendered" v-bind="{ active, duration }">
    <div class="wrap">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut, consequatur
      ut magnam, quos possimus, velit quam mollitia voluptate adipisci
      reiciendis sapiente accusamus ullam ab voluptatem laborum non! Accusamus,
      ullam, voluptatum.
    </div>
  </slide-up-down>
</div>
```

**Vue3 demo**:

```js
const { createApp, reactive, computed, nextTick, toRefs } = Vue
const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      isRendered: false,
      active: false,
      duration: 500,
      rendered: computed({
        get() { return state.isRendered },
        set(val) {
          if (val) {
            state.isRendered = val
            nextTick(() => {
              state.active = val
            })
          } else {
            state.active = val
            setTimeout(() => {
              state.isRendered = val
            }, state.duration)
          }
        }
      })
    })
    return toRefs(state)
  }
})
app.component("slide-up-down", Vue3SlideUpDown)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
.wrap {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

button {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.47/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue3-slide-up-down@1.2.5/dist/vue3-slide-up-down.umd.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="rendered = !rendered">Toggle</button>
  <slide-up-down v-if="isRendered" v-model="active" v-bind="{ duration }">
    <div class="wrap">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut, consequatur
      ut magnam, quos possimus, velit quam mollitia voluptate adipisci
      reiciendis sapiente accusamus ullam ab voluptatem laborum non! Accusamus,
      ullam, voluptatum.
    </div>
  </slide-up-down>
</div>
```

---

If you're gonna do this multiple times, you might want to extract it as a stand-alone component. Usage example:

```html
<conditional-slide :rendered="condition" :duration="1000">
  <div>content you want rendered based on `this.condition` (boolean)</div>
</conditional-slide>
```

Since the change now comes from the `rendered` prop, you can move the computed setter code into a `watch`:

In **Vue 2**:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <slide-up-down
      v-if="isRendered"
      v-bind="{ active, duration }"
    >
      <slot />
    </slide-up-down>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import SlideUpDown from 'vue-slide-up-down'
export default {
  components: { SlideUpDown },
  props: {
    rendered: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    duration: {
      type: Number,
      default: 500
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    active: false,
    isRendered: false
  }),
  watch: {
    rendered: {
      handler(val) {
        if (val) {
          this.isRendered = val
          this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.active = val
          })
        } else {
          this.active = val
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.isRendered = val
          }, this.duration)
        }
      },
      immediate: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

---

[Vue 3 example](https://xomou7-5173.preview.csb.app/). Sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/slide-up-down-xomou7).

---

- feel free to add more props and pass them down to the inner `<slide-up-down />`.
- note the vue2 and vue3 versions use different forks of the same plugin (pay attention to the imports) and have slightly different template syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, there is the solution.

Use `v-show` instead of `v-if`

I have used the original example from the `vue-slide-up-down` site to demonstrate the behavior.

If you use 'v-show' and also toggle the `v-slide-` component together, then you have the slide effect when your hidden content will be show again.

```js
Vue.component("slide-up-down", VueSlideUpDown);
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
      active: false,
      show: true,
      contentLength: 2,
      showOptions: false,
      useHidden: true,
      timing: "",
      duration: 500
   }),
   methods: {
      toggle() {
        this.active = !this.active;
      },
      toggleShow() {
        this.show = !this.show;
        this.active = this.show;
      }
    }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
#app {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 700px;
}
.Button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.Button.small {
  width: auto;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 0;
}
.AccordionWrapper {
  background-color: darkred;
}
.AccordionWrapper.easeInOutCirc {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
}
.AccordionWrapper.customTiming {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.195, 1.65, 0.435, -0.6);
}
.Accordion {
  display: block;
  width: 96%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.Accordion p,
.Accordion hr {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.Accordion p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">  
  <div v-show="show">
    <button @click="toggle" class="Button">Toggle Content</button>
     <slide-up-down class="AccordionWrapper" :active="active" :use-hidden="this.useHidden" :class="this.timing" :duration="this.duration"> 
      <div class="Accordion">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut, consequatur ut magnam, quos possimus, velit quam mollitia voluptate adipisci reiciendis sapiente accusamus ullam ab voluptatem laborum non! Accusamus, ullam, voluptatum.</p>
      </div>
    </slide-up-down>
    </div>
   <button class="Button" @click="toggleShow">Toggle if elements exists</button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.7.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-slide-up-down@2.0.0/dist/vue-slide-up-down.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and I am sorry about failed the expressing what I want. I'll try to do it again referring to your example. Can you  **remove the AccordionWrapper from the DOM** once it became invisible? And then, can you mount it to DOM again between "Toggle Content" clicked again and animation starting? Currently, the AccordionWrapper still presents in DOM after became invisible while the target is remove if from the DOM, not just to hide.